# Google Drive API - Allocating Quota for a 3rd party app

Tags: google-drive-api

**Intro**

1. Google provide ~5Gb of storage space to it's subscribers
2. This storage can be used to store arbitrary files
3. Google has published API to interact with the storage, namely GDrive SDK

**Use case:**

- A 3rd party application ( e.g. WebSite the user is subscribed to ) is granted access to part of the Subscribers GDrive storage ( a Quota )
- The application manage the allocated Quota on behalf of the user.
- Part of the content on the managed Quota can be accessed by the wide public ( controlled by the 3rd part app ).

Does Google support the above mentioned use-case? in what way? Is there any other application supporting such a use-case?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really good use-case, thanks for raising it. Sorry, unfortunately it is not currently possible with the Google Drive SDK.